# Python Cassandra driver not installed, or not on PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, linux, cassandra

I am getting the below error while running the cqlsh in cassandra 2.2.10 ?? Can somebody help me to pass this hurdle:

> [root@rac1 site-packages]# $CASSANDRA_PATH/bin/cqlsh
>
> Python Cassandra driver not installed, or not on PYTHONPATH. You might
>   try “pip install cassandra-driver”.
>
> Python: /usr/local/bin/python Module load path:
>   [‘/opt/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.2.10/bin/../lib/six-1.7.3-py2.py3-none-any.zip’,
>   ‘/opt/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.2.10/bin/../lib/futures-2.1.6-py2.py3-none-any.zip’,
>   ‘/opt/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.2.10/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.5.0.post0-d8d0456.zip/cassandra-driver-3.5.0.post0-d8d0456’,
>   ‘/opt/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.2.10/bin’,
>   ‘/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages’,
>   ‘/usr/local/lib/python27.zip’, ‘/usr/local/lib/python2.7’,
>   ‘/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2’,
>   ‘/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk’, ‘/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old’,
>   ‘/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload’]
>
> Error: can’t decompress data; zlib not available

Comment: Error message says it all: install `cassandra-driver` using `pip install cassandra-driver`.

Comment: Hi Prateek I have also facing same issue, did you found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra uses the python driver bundled in-tree in a zip file. If your Python runtime was not built with `zlib` support, it cannot use the zip archive in the `PYTHONPATH`. Either install the driver directly (`pip install`) as suggested, or put a correctly configured Python runtime in your path.

Answer (score 0):

For me (ubuntu 20.04, cassandra 3.11.13), the symbolic link `/usr/bin/python` was pointing to `/usr/bin/python3`.

When changing it to point to `/usr/bin/python2`, it worked.

```bash
ln -sf /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python
```